# Flutter ScrollController not working under StreamBuilder with ConnectionState condition

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new with flutter & just learned how to retrieve data from firestore & did some UI. Right now I have 2 problems;

**1- This is a Setting Page which has `CustomScrollView` contains `ScrollController` for the controller.**

[SettingsPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z4df.gif)

The controller working fine with this code

```
class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Shared.firestore.collection('client').document(Shared.firebaseUser.uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    expandedHeight: 140.0,
                    pinned: true,
                  ),
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 8,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 18.0,
                                    top: 18.0,
                                  ),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Account",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.blue[700],
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                child: ListTile(
                                  onTap: () {},
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
                                  title: Text(
                                    "+${snapshot.data['countryCode']} ${snapshot.data['phoneNumber']}",
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Phone Number",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

but this error happened

```
I/flutter ( 8691): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8691): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 8691): _StreamBuilderBaseState<DocumentSnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot>>#7db43):
I/flutter ( 8691): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 8691): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 8691): Tried calling: []("countryCode")
I/flutter ( 8691):
I/flutter ( 8691): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8691): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #1      _SettingsPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:silkwallet/page/settings.dart:81:54)
I/flutter ( 8691): #2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:423:74)
I/flutter ( 8691): #3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:125:48)
I/flutter ( 8691): #4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27)
I/flutter ( 8691): #5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
I/flutter ( 8691): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #7      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter ( 8691): #9      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 8691): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 8691): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter ( 8691): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #15     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
I/flutter ( 8691): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 8691): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 8691): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
I/flutter ( 8691): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 8691): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
I/flutter ( 8691): #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
I/flutter ( 8691): #23     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #24     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #25     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
I/flutter ( 8691): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
.
.
.
I/flutter ( 8691): #135    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #136    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 8691): #137    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 8691): #138    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 8691): #139    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
I/flutter ( 8691): #140    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
```

**2- After some research for this error, I add `connectionState` condition inside `StreamBuilder` which solved above problem**

this is the new code, i put the `Scaffold` inside active `connectionState`

```
class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Shared.firestore.collection('client').document(Shared.firebaseUser.uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
            body: Stack(
              .
              .
              .
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
        } else {
          return Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.warning),
                ),
                Text('Error in loadind data')
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and I realized that when I scrolled the connectionState will change to waiting and the ScrollController not working under this state as shown in the image below

[ScrollController: page keep flashing when try to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVixc.gif)

The reason I want to use the `ScrollController` because I want to add `FloatingActionButton` inside `Positioned` which will scroll along & disappear when reach certain position, here's the image [with FloatingActionButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I79l.gif)

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError the method was called on null` errors are usually thrown when the method that you're trying to call from the object is yet to be initialized. The error seems to be coming from `snapshot.data['countryCode']`. What you can do here is add a null-check on snapshot before displaying the data.

```dart
if (snapshot != null && snapshot.hasData) {
  // Display data
} else {
  // Display circular progress...
}
```